# Is a Circle of Stars Druid's Chalice form affected by Grave Cleric's Circle of Mortality?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, healing

If a Stars Druid/Grave Cleric multiclass were to use a Cure Wounds on an unconscious creature at 0 hp, and they designate that creature as a target of their Chalice form's healing ability, does that mean they receive 16+double wisdom mod healing, or 8+1d8+double wisdom mod healing?

> **Circle of Mortality**...  When you would normally roll one or more dice to restore hit points with a spell to a creature at 0 hit points, you instead use the highest number possible for each die.

> **Chalice**...  Whenever you cast a spell using a spell slot that restores hit points to a creature, you or another creature within 30 feet of you can regain hit points equal to 1d8 + your Wisdom modifier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The extra healing from Chalice is not from a spell

The effect doing the extra healing is from the class ability, so the total healing is "8 + 1d8 + double wisdom modifier" as you stated.

The cleric ability only affects spells, so it cannot maximise the healing from the druid ability.